# Trying to run Jest on React Native, multiple Errors occur, last one is: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createAnimatedComponent' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, jestjs, babel-jest

I am new to Jest. I'm trying to run it with the most basic test:

```
//App-test.js
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';


// Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<App />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

But I keep getting the Error: ● Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createAnimatedComponent' of undefined

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-screens/lib/commonjs/index.js:27:23)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-navigation-tabs/lib/commonjs/navigato/createBottomTabNavigator.tsx:10:1)
```

My jest config in my package.json looks like this:

```
 "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "globals": {
      "__DEV__": true
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!react-native-screens|react-navigation-tabs)/",
      "node_modules/(?!react-native-payfort-sdk|react-native|Hacktor|react-native-button|react-navigation)/"
    ],
    "haste": {
      "defaultPlatform": "android",
      "platforms": [
        "android",
        "ios"
      ]
    }
  }
```

and my babel.config.js looks like this:

```
// babel.config.js
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  const presets = [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        modules: 'auto',
        useBuiltIns: 'entry'
      }
    ],
    '@babel/react',
    '@babel/preset-flow'
  ];
  const plugins = [
    '@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/transform-runtime',
    'add-module-exports',
    
  ];

  return {
    presets,
    plugins
  };
};
```

I don't know what I can do anymore. My code is so full because with the most basic settings I was getting every error possible. I'm also running a basic addition test which looks like that:

```
const functions = require('./functions');

test('Adds 2+2 to equal 4', ()=> {
    expect(functions.add(2,2)).toBe(4);
});
```

which works just fine.

EDIT:
I redid TransformIgnorePatterns like so:

```
 "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-navigation|@react-native-community|@react-navigation/.*)"
      
    ],
```

And the Error is still this:
● Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createAnimatedComponent' of undefined

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-screens/lib/commonjs/index.js:27:23)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-navigation-tabs/lib/commonjs/navigators/createBottomTabNavigator.tsx:10:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```js
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-navigation|@react-native-community|@react-navigation/.*)"
    ],
```

Comment: Thank you for Your answer! The problem still occurs. It still says:   ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'createAnimatedComponent' of undefined

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-screens/lib/commonjs/index.js:27:23)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-navigation-tabs/lib/commonjs/navigators/createBottomTabNavigator.tsx:10:1)